# Asynchronous Flask functions

Tags: python, asynchronous, flask, celery

I have an app in flask that I need to perform some asynchronous action on.  I've read about celery, but not sure if it's correct.

Basically I have a button that takes input and runs a query to return back to the template, and this is quick, but I want it to also run another task (passing a SOAP envelope against a web service), and this is slow.  I don't want the user to have to wait for the web-service call to finish.  I'd like for the query running the return back to the template with new data to happen as quickly as possible and the web-service call to happen in the background.

Is this doable?

Comment: This is exactly what Celery is for.

Comment: Cool.  Thinking of using Redis for the broker.  Do I need to do anything else on the server to utilize Redis?  RabbitMQ seems like it requires the overhead of an install.  Will running celeryt as a daemon and calling Redis from the celery config be enough?

Comment: Should be. I prefer running Celery under upstart, but whatever you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there are lots of Celery related threads here, but this might provide some service.

Using Celery for asynchronous activity requires more than just installing and importing the lib.

Requirements:

```
Celery lib
Queue broker, like Redis (in memory db), installed
Separate file that creates celery object
```

I found the Flask documentation on Celery with flask lacking.  My preferred method was to create a tasks.py file and put in

```
from celery import Celery
# Other imports for functionality here

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379')

@app.tasks
def your_function(args):
    do something with args
    return something
```

Then in the application file make sure this is imported:

```
from tasks import your_function
```

And then use it where you need to in the app

```
your_function(args)
```

Then you must make sure that a celery daemon/worker is running.  This can be done by init, by systemd, by launchctl or manually at the CLI (not ideal).  Redis must also be running and listening on the url you give it.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need tornado! Asynchronous web server gateway compatible with flask

```
from tornado.wsgi import WSGIContainer
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from YourModule import app

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(8080)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I prefer tornado for its speed, reliability, and simplicity with Flask, which I love for its beauty